# Ruby on rails, form isn't passing part of a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I'm trying to invite new users to a web application. I have the following code:

```
 = f.fields_for(:memberships, Membership.new(:user => User.new( :account => Account.new( :invited_by => current_profile))), :child_index => 'new_membership') do |ff|
          = ff.fields_for :user do |user_fields|
            = user_fields.fields_for :account do |account_fields|
              = account_fields.hidden_field :invited_by_id
              %div{:class => "label_top field"}
                = account_fields.label :email
                - if account_fields.object.new_record?
                  = account_fields.text_field :email
                - else
                  = account_fields.object.email
            %div{:class => "label_top field"}
              = user_fields.label :first_name
              = user_fields.text_field :first_name
            %div{:class => "label_top field"}
              = user_fields.label :last_name
              = user_fields.text_field :last_name
          = ff.hidden_field :pending
```

On my website, members of the site have two parts: an account and the type of account. First you create an account and then your type is defined later. In this case, we're working with a user type account. Users and accounts are two different models. This code create a user membership to a project. If the the user is not signed up to the website yet, this particular form creates the membership and also creates a new account of the type user.

The user part of the model seems to work (ie first and last name are being saved), however, the account part of the model (email) is not being saved. Any recommendations? My guess is that the e-mail parameter is not being passed correctly to the Account model, though not quite sure how to check which parameters are being sent either.

Comment: The parameters appear in the log.

Comment: check your attr_accessible - is `accounts_attributes` there?

Comment: Got it! It seems that the User model was not accepting nested attributes for the Account model.